# Bash-Scripting: Using find and move inside a script does not work properly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

unfortunately I run into a problem while bash-scripting.

What I am trying to achieve is:

- I want to create a script, that takes some user input as keyword / searchword.
- The script should use `find` to search for the user input and present it with `print`.
- In case the user is satisfied the script should be ordered to move those files to a destinationfolder using `find "$searchpath" -iname "$findword" -type f -exec mv {} "$destinationpath/$season" \;` to move these files.

This is how my script looks like. Attention a NOOB is SCRIPTING HERE!

```
cat find_and_move.sh 
#!/bin/bash

#keyword
#searchpath
#Smin
#Smax
#season
#destinationpath
#findword
#allfine

while getopts "k:p:d:n:m:x" opt; do

     case $opt in 

        k)
        keyword=$OPTARG ;;
        #get one keyword

        p)
        searchpath=$OPTARG ;;
        #get searchpath ( where to find the keyword )

        n)
        Smin="$(printf '%d' $OPTARG 2>/dev/null)" ;; 
        #convert string to number and save as Smin

        m)
        Smax="$(printf '%d' $OPTARG 2>/dev/null)" ;;
        #convert string to number and save as Smax

        d)
        destinationpath=$OPTARG ;;
        #get destinationpath to copy to

        \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2 
        exit 1 ;;

        :)
        echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2 
        exit 1 ;; 

     esac
done

#Check if all parameters are set.
if [ -z "$keyword" ]; then echo "keyword is NULL"; 
   else if [ -z "$searchpath" ]; then echo "searchpath is NULL"; 
   else if [ -z "$Smin" ]; then echo "Smin is NULL"; 
   else if [ -z "$Smax" ]; then echo "Smax is NULL"; 
   else if [ -z "$destinationpath" ]; then echo "Destinationpath is NULL"; 
   else echo "ALL PARAMETERS SET";
   allfine="true";

   fi 
   fi 
   fi 
   fi 
 fi


#MAIN: Find and print the result
if [ -z $allfine ]; then echo "allfine is NULL"; 
  else if [ $allfine = "true" ]; then echo "Allfine = true"  

        while [ $Smin -le $Smax ]
        do
                if [ $Smin -le $Smax ] ; 
                   then season="S0$Smin"
                   else season="S$Smin"
                fi
                findword="*$keyword*$season*"
                echo $findword
                echo find $searchpath -iname $findword -type f -print
                find "$searchpath" -iname "$findword" -type f -print
# this search with find works properly

                echo "find $searchpath -iname $findword -type f -exec mv {} $destinationpath/$season \;"
                #find "$searchpath -iname $findword -type f -exec {} $destinationpath/$season \;"
                let Smin++
                sleep 2;
        done;

#If user is satisfied with the result of find&print then order the script to move the files.
        echo "Do you really want to move the files?" 
        read -p "" -n 1 -r
        echo    # (optional) move to a new line
        if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
                then
                exit 1
        fi
        echo "Files will be moved now."
        sleep 2;

        while [ $Smin -le $Smax ]
         do
                 if [ $Smin -le $Smax ] ; 
                    then season="S0$Smin"
                    else season="S$Smin"
                 fi
                 findword="*$keyword*$season*"
                 echo $findword
                 echo find $searchpath -iname $findword -type f -print            
                 find $searchpath -iname $findword -type f -print
#this find search with print works properly
                 echo "find $searchpath -iname $findword -type f -exec mv {} $destinationpath/$season \;"
#the output of echo is correct and works using copy and paste in terminal
                 find "$searchpath" -iname "$findword" -type f -exec mv {} "$destinationpath/$season" \;
#this find -exec mv command seems to be ignored. No error is shown.
                 let Smin++
                 sleep 2;
         done;


        exit 1


  fi
fi
```

When I call that script with `./find_and_move.sh -k mykeyword -p mysearchpath -d destinationfolder -n low-number -m high-number`everything works fine except that it does not move the files. Also I do not receive any error message.

When I copy and paste the result of `echo "find $searchpath -iname $findword -type f -exec mv {} $destinationpath/$season \;"` to the terminal the move of the files works without problems. Without `echo` the command seems to be ignored (check my last three comments in the script).

Comment: You are trying to run `find` twice: Once to present the user with the list of files, and then again to actually move the files. This is dangerous prone (if the two invocations are not identical), and error-prone (if something changes in the file system between the two calls). Instead I suggest that you create first a bash array of those files you want to move, and then process this array to actually move the files.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you for your suggestions to make the script more safe. I am new to bash scripting and creating arrays will make things even more complex for me. Further more I will be the onlyone using the script and the computer where it will be running. And as said, the move command seems to be ignored, and i still dont know why.

Comment: Actually, I believe that using the array will not only be simpler, it also will make your error go away ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT April 26th**

I have modified many things in your script, have a look:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage()
{
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: $0 -k <keyword> -p <search path> -d <destination folder> -n <value> -m <value>"
    exit 1
}

while getopts "k:p:d:n:m:x" opt
do
    case $opt in
        k)
            #get one keyword
            keyword="$OPTARG"
        ;;
        p)
            #get searchpath ( where to find the keyword )
            searchpath="$OPTARG"
        ;;
        n)
            #convert string to number and save as Smin
            Smin="$OPTARG"
        ;;
        m)
            #convert string to number and save as Smax
            Smax="$OPTARG"
        ;;
        d)
            #get destinationpath to copy to
            destinationpath="$OPTARG"
        ;;
        \?)
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            usage
        ;;
        *)
            echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
            usage
        ;;
    esac
done

#Check if all parameters are set.
if [ -z "$keyword" ]
then
    echo "keyword is NULL"
    usage
elif [ -z "$searchpath" ]
then
    echo "searchpath is NULL"
    usage
elif [ -z "$Smin" ]
then
    echo "Smin is NULL"
    usage
elif [ -z "$Smax" ]
then
    echo "Smax is NULL"
    usage
elif [ -z "$destinationpath" ]
then
    echo "destinationpath is NULL"
    usage
fi

#DEBUG
echo "keyword=$keyword"
echo "searchpath=$searchpath"
echo "Smin=$Smin"
echo "Smax=$Smax"
echo "destinationpath=$destinationpath"

#MAIN: Find and print the result
whilemin1="$Smin"
while [[ "$whilemin1" -le "$Smax" ]]
do
    echo ""
    season="S0$whilemin1"
    findword="*$keyword*$season*"
    echo "findword=$findword"
    echo "Running: find \"$searchpath\" -iname \"$findword\" -type f -print"
    find "$searchpath" -iname "$findword" -type f -print
    (( whilemin1++ ))
    sleep 2
done

#If user is satisfied with the result of find&print then order the script to move the files.
echo ""
read -p "Do you really want to move the files? " -n 1 -r
if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    echo -e "\nNo files moved."
    #exit 1
else
    echo -e "\nFiles will be moved now."
    sleep 2
fi

whilemin2="$Smin"
while [[ "$whilemin2" -le "$Smax" ]]
do
    echo ""
    season="S0$whilemin2"
    findword="*$keyword*$season*"
    echo "findword=$findword"
    echo "Running: find \"$searchpath\" -iname \"$findword\" -type f -exec mv -t \"./$destinationpath/$season\" {} +"
    find "$searchpath" -iname "$findword" -type f -exec mv -t "./$destinationpath/$season" {} +
    (( whilemin2++ ))
    sleep 2
done
```

- IMHO, you should name your script `find_and_move.bash`, since your `#!` line is bash.
- Indented the entire code to make is simpler to see code blocks.
- Removed all the `;` that you had all over the place, not required.
- Created a `usage` function, since there are many situations where you want to exit on command syntax issues.
- No need for the `printf` to convert option values into numbers, bash does not really care.  If you use number operators on a variable value, it takes care of it for you.
- Removed the `allfine` concept all together, if any parameter is empty, the script exists anyway.
- Removed your `if then else if then else if ...` and put `if then elif else fi` instead.  Simpler to read.
- In your first `while` you have both `find` commands.  And in the second one again.  I put the `find ... -print` in the first `while`, the `find ... -exec ...` in the second while.
- Removed the `if [ $Smin -le $Smax ]` inside the `while` statements.  It is impossible to enter the `while` if this condition is not true anyway, so why check it again.
- For `read`, no need for an `echo` before, just put the question as an argument to `read`.
- Removed old `let` command, replaced with `(( ))` syntax.
- Ran the code through site https://www.shellcheck.net/ to ensure no syntax issues remained.

I tested with what I **think** you want your script to do.  But since you did not provide a complete set of test directories and files structure, it is possible I did not test the proper thing.

**Note**: the suggestion in the comments to avoid looping twice by storing filenames in an array is quite right, but I did not want to jump into that.  If your number of files is small and filesystem changes are few, your script will work.  YMMV.

**EDIT NOTE**: the reason why it did not work is the first `while` incremented `Smin`, therefore the second `while` uses that incremented value, so it never enters the `while` loop.  The modified version now uses new variables for each `while` condition.

**EDIT NOTE 2**: the `find` was modified to avoid the "file ... already exists" error message.  `... -exec mv -t "./$destinationpath/$season" {} +`

Comment: I do really appreciate your help. Thank you very much. Unfortunately it does not work. I have created a pastebin for you. Perhaps you can recreate my problem. https://pastebin.com/LP3X6NuR Again big thank you for all of your corrections. I will try to learn from your tips.

Comment: The pastebin was very helpful to get a proper test case.  I modified the script to fix the `while` condition problem, and the `find` command that moves the files to avoid the "already exists" messages.